# Linux GUI to track connections made from/to this computer

Tags: networking, firewall, notifications, real-time

Is there a GUI to track any socket connection sent to this computer and which program that initiates it?

Also if possible track any incoming connection sent to this computer and which program that handles it (as a realtime popup indicator if possible) ?

For example:

```
"/bin/x owned by user x tries to connect to x.x.x.x:x"
"x.x.x.x connected to your computer on port 80 handled by /usr/bin/apache"
```

or at minimum, what should I learn to create this kind of software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is old school console tool:

```
   nethogs - Net top tool grouping bandwidth per process
```

e.g. run in this manner:

```
# nethogs eth0

NetHogs version 0.8.0

  PID USER    PROGRAM            DEV        SENT       RECEIVED      
11173 user    rtorrent          eth0     111.001       4.358 KB/sec
13159 user    rtorrent          eth0     125.673       3.734 KB/sec
9737  user    irssi             eth0       0.027       0.1
9687  user    chromium-browser  eth0       0.000       0.000 KB/sec
```

You can browser the [developer's site](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net), for more information and more such tools.

Now you can grab the source, make your own fork and develop kind of GUI.
Appending sockets info with fidelity near bandwidth not a great job.